# tomcat node member of a cluster is using up all the CPU

Tags: java, tomcat, cluster-computing, cpu, redhat

I am having the following issue. 
On a red hat 6.5 I have 3 tomcats running in a cluster with an appache in front of them acting as a loadbalancer. As you see the example output of TOP only one of the tomcats is using up CPU time while the other 2 nodes are not loaded at all. Notice also that only one of the CPU is being used at a time. I have monitored it for a while and the load is floating between the 4 CPUs but always staying around 99%.

Any hints, tips and tricks are most welcome. Any suggestions where to look and check would come as a Christmas gift :P

```
 Cpu0  :  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.7%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  : 99.7%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  37017852k total, 35690252k used,  1327600k free,   401980k buffers
Swap:  7340016k total,        0k used,  7340016k free, 20737836k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
24633 tomcat3  20   0 6938m 3.0g  19m S 100.3  8.4 592:49.00 java
```

Comment: Tried to ask  this also on http://serverfault.com/?

Comment: Well.. find the busy loop in your app? Your stat not only shows one tomcat is responsible for the load but also that it's most likely one single thread (thus only running on one Cpu at that time) consuming all your cycles.

Comment: i have done thread dump and am examining it with Thread Dump Analyses. No DEADLOCKS found, only a lot of threads with state = BLOCKED. Should i dive in to the Heap dump ?

Comment: yes. or share some of those BLOCKED here

Comment: Thread 29119: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)

Comment: Thread 29010: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)

Comment: Thread 28807: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Compiled frame)

Comment: Hope that is enough.

Comment: You should edit your question to contain the extra information, rather than commenting. Also, BLOCKED threads probably don't eat up a lot of CPU, while running threads do. Figure out which ones are running (from the thread dump) and check for them, rather than looking for blocked threads.